# What does "sucking on the night as it came"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> A towering, hooded figure was gliding smoothly toward him, hovering over the ground, no feet or face visible beneath its robes, **sucking on the night as it came**.
>
> —Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix

How does one suck on *the night*? and does *as it came* mean *when it came*?

Comment: You are right on your assumption about **as it came**. It, indeed means **when it came**. And I believe **sucking on night** is a figurative phrase or wordings. It means **through the night air**.

Comment: Doesn't _on the night_ simply mean _at night_? Dementors are nocturnal? I've not read Harry Potter Series.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Actually it is **(suck on) the night**. If you suck on your finger, you put your finger in your mouth and pull on it using your tongue and lips.

Comment: I don't think so. It's that they are sucking in the evening. @Man_From_India

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng in the night or at night sound more natural if Rowling wanted it to mean it happened during the night. And she had no reason to emphasise it's night again. I think she went for the figurative approach this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dementors (to which the quote refers) are creatures that suck the psychic energy out of people. *Sucking on the night* is a poetic image. It doesn't really have a literal meaning. It is meant to create a picture in your mind of this thing that is trying to suck the energy out of Harry.

"As it came" means as it—the dementor—came towards Harry. "As" here means "at the same time as". The dementor was "sucking on the night", and at the same time as it was doing that, it was coming towards Harry.